.NET - Integration testing with middleware (PACT)
Hey,
I write consumer tests using the PACT framework. And I'm trying to run WebApplication factory. I have the following settings. And in case when I use middleware my all endpoints return 404. Do you know why? Am I registering the wrong middleware? Thanks a lot
It's really whatever I call it. Endpoint is a dump, it just returns data. It works without adding middleware. But it's also true that I can't configure services. I have to start up factory like this because of PACT, which needs the application to run on tcp.
Factory
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private IHost? _host;

    public string ServerAddress
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureServer();
            return ClientOptions.BaseAddress.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Configure(app =>
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Custom middleware executed before next middleware.");

                await next.Invoke();

                Console.WriteLine("Custom middleware executed after next middleware.");
            });
        });
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {          
        var testHost = builder.Build();

        builder.ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.UseKestrel();
        });

        _host = builder.Build();
        _host.Start();

        var server = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
        var addresses = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

        ClientOptions.BaseAddress = addresses!.Addresses
            .Select(x => new Uri(x))
            .Last();

        testHost.Start();
        return testHost;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _host?.Dispose();
    }

    private void EnsureServer()
    {
        if (_host is null)
        {
            using var _ = CreateDefaultClient();
        }
    }
}

Test:
 public class ProductTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
 {
     private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;
     private readonly string _serverAddress;
     private readonly HttpClient? _trop;
     private readonly ITestService _testService;

     public ProductTest(ITestOutputHelper output, CustomWebApplicationFactory fixture)
     {
         _output = output;
         _serverAddress = fixture.ServerAddress;
         _trop = fixture.CreateClient();
     }

     [Fact]
     public async Task EnsureProviderApiHonoursPactWithConsumer()
     {
         var lorto = await _trop.GetAsync($"/api/products");
     }
 }

